# Can't open files

Tags: filesystem, 19.04, bug-reporting

I recently updated from ubuntu 18 to 19.04.
But as expected this version has many bugs.
The system performs much slower(might be because of my outdated hardware).
It was manageable until now. I recently encountered this bug, where I'm unable to open my files.
I tried to restart system thousand times but no change.
It just shows "Files" beside Activities and then just disappears,opening nothing.

EDIT: I received a comment asking me to to try and run nautilus on terminal. Surprisingly it opened this time and now it works.
however I noticed this message on terminal:

```
Nautilus-Share-Message: 18:22:47.675: Called "net usershare info" but it failed: Failed to execute child process “net” (No such file or directory)
```

I don't know what that means, Thanks for the help :) @pLumo

Comment: Do a fresh install.

Comment: its will open some time its happen :D restart pc and wait

Comment: For me 19.04 has less issues than 18.04 and is way faster due to gnome-shell 3.32 vs 3.28.

Comment: Please open a terminal and run `nautilus`. What happens? Is there any error message? If yes, edit your question and copy-paste the error into it.

Comment: Ubuntu 19.04 does not have many bugs as such. May depend on your specific system.